# Issue with Erf function and comparaison with Maple

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I warn you that I am completely new to Mathematica and I apologize in advance if my question is very stupid.

I define the function $f(x)$ in the following way (it is very close to the function ${\rm Erf}(x)$):

```
f[x_]:= Integrate [Exp [-y ^ 2], {y, -inf, x}]
```

When I validate the entry, Mathematica seems to hang for many minutes. Same thing when I want a graphical representation of the function $f(x)$ with `Plot`. In the end, I still get the result but it really takes a long time.

Is there something that I am doing wrong? I am amazed because the result is almost immediate in Maple (I don't want to have a sterile debate between Mathematica and Maple, I just want to understand).

Comment: 1) use `Infinity` instead of inf, 2) use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) because with `Set` it will evaluate the integral symbolically once and you can use it later with numerical substitutions, whereas `SetDelayed` will calculate the integral on every invocation of `f` which is slow. 3) You could just write `f[x_]:=1/2 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + Erf[x])`

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at what your definition actually produces.

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-y^2], {y, -inf, x}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 Sqrt[π] (Erf[inf] + Erf[x])
> ```

That's not what you want. What you want is:

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-y^2], {y, -Infinity, x}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 Sqrt[π] (1 + Erf[x])
> ```

With this definition the plotting will be instantaneous for all practical purposes.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -12., 12.}]
```

[image: plot]

You can also write your definition as:

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-y^2], {y, -∞, x}]
```

in a Mathematica notebook, where ∞ is entered by <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>inf</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.